# Does Force telekenesis/choke make an in-universe sound or is it only an auditory cue for the audience?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, telekinesis, sound-effects

There are many examples of Force telekenesis making a "blood rushing to the head" type of wooshing sound effect in much of the *Star Wars* canon. But it has never been clear to me whether or not this sound was made as an auditory cue for the audience, or if it was audible to the characters as well. Is there any evidence one way or the other in either canon or Legends?

Comment: iirc, other types of force powers also create *whoOosh* effects, ex: force push and leaping using the force. Doesn't say anything about whether it is for audience benefit, but it's not limited to just force choke. One way to potentially figure this one out is to see if any noisy force powers have been recorded on holodisks, hologram transmissions, and so on (I *think* this is likely in the Clone Wars series).

Comment: The only sound the Force makes in the original trilogy is thunder, and Ben's distraction which doesn't even have an auditory cue.

Comment: Clearly everyone heard the person getting choked to death by Darth Vader in *The Empire strikes back*

Answer (score 1):

### Partial answer: unclear, but it behaves like a sound in the room

I haven't found any sources that describe this sound in-universe, but when the sound does appear in canon sources, it's only audible when the camera is near the target of the Force power. It plays in this scene where Vader is choking Captain Needa while in the same room (0:28):

...but it *doesn't* play in this scene where Vader is remotely choking Admiral Ozzel, who we see on a viewscreen (0:52):

It does, however, play in these scenes where a hologram of a Force-user is choking or throwing around someone who's in the same room as the camera:

This implies that the sound is either diegetic and only occurs at the site of choking, or is non-diegetic but is only used for scenes where the target of the Force power is present.

Comment: I had always thought it was the sound of the victim's blood in their ears (think of the sound if you plug your ears).

Comment: @Xantec The sound plays in some works where no one's getting choked; see for example this clip from Vader Immortal: https://youtu.be/eHPD2zQpzxg?t=643.